# setState for an object React Native undefined not an object(evaluting'features.filter')

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native

I am building a project using React Native, I have a state of different routs that is being selected from a drop-down, so according to the selected value I wanna return a Json file (Routs credentials)
so I am filtering the input using a function  AreaFiltration() and the state to change the route(line) according to the JSON file

```
const [onToggleArea, setonToggleArea] = useState(Line1)
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions,Text } from "react-native";
import madar1 from './jsonRouts/madar1.json'
import Line1 from './jsonRouts/Line1.json'


import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

function app() {
  const [onToggleArea, setonToggleArea] = useState(Line1)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(['Area']);
  const [selectedArea, setSelectedArea] = useState([
    {label: 'first Route', value: 'one', key:1},
    {label: 'Secont Route', value: 'two', key:2},

  ]);


  const AreaFiltration =(x)=> {
    const brakeData = x[x.length - 1].toString()
    if(brakeData === 'one') return {Line1}
    if(brakeData === 'two') return {madar1}

    return brakeData
    
  }
    const onChangeValue = (e) => {
        const getAreaValue = AreaFiltration(e)
        setonToggleArea(brakeData)     
    }
  
  
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
   
    }}>
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={selectedArea}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={setValue}
        setItems={setSelectedArea}
        onChangeValue={onChangeValue}
        theme="LIGHT"
        multiple={true}
        mode="BADGE"
    </View>

        <Geojson 
          geojson={onToggleArea}
          strokeColor="rgba(255,0,0,0.3)"
          fillColor="rgba(124,252,2,0.5)"
          strokeWidth={8}
        />


      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}

;

export default app;
```

when I console.log the area, I get the correct value

```
   const onChangeValue = (e) => {
        const getAreaValue = AreaFiltration(e)
        console.log(getAreaValue)
    }
```

**but when I set state inside onChangeValue**

```
const onChangeValue = (e) => {
        const getAreaValue = AreaFiltration(e)
        setonToggleArea(getAreaValue)
    }
```

but I am getting this Error:
`undefined not an object(evaluting'features.filter')`

the imported JSON FILE:

```
{
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                35.88139111751471,
                32.05637500145676
              ],
```

what I see on the Console

```
Object {
  "Line1": Object {
    "features": Array [
      Object {
        "geometry": Object {
          "coordinates": Array [
            Array [
              Array [
                35.88139111751471,
                32.05637500145676,
              ],
```

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to set the state to an object, not the value of the object. The setonToggleArea function expects a value, not an object.

To solve this issue, you can update your onChangeValue function to something like this:

const onChangeValue = (e) => {
  const getAreaValue = AreaFiltration(e)
  setonToggleArea(getAreaValue.value)
}

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Talha 
using getAreaValue.value returns 'undefined'

Comment: If getAreaValue.value is returning 'undefined', then you may need to check the value of getAreaValue to make sure it is returning the correct value. If it is returning the correct value, then you may need to adjust your AreaFiltration function to return the correct value.

Comment: it's confusing because whenever I console the results it returns an object of arrays, which is correct 
```` Object {
  "Line1": Object {
    "features": Array [
      Object {
        "geometry": Object {`````

however, when I try to use any of the object's attributes even in the console, it returns an undefined .. I think the filtration is correct since it returns an object, I will try to modify the the JSON file and see how it goes